# In ASP.Net C# would the Application end when and error occurs on the site or when Application_Error is triggered

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello brilliant guys on Stackoverflow, please I would like to know if in ASP.Net C# would the Application end when an error occurs or when Application_Error is triggered? From my understanding, it shouldn't, I just want to be double sure

Comment: First day in SO !!! have you read this **http://stackoverflow.com/faq** ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if an exception happens in a thread associated with a request, it triggers Application_Error event and if not handled will return a HTTP 500 error to the client.

But, an un-handled exception in a thread not associated with a request will take down the worker process (in other words, kills your application). This occurs even if you have a handler setup via the Application_Error method. [MSDN Link for Exception in Managed Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965.aspx) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, will throw you to a HTTP 500 error page if you're not handling exceptions.

The application itself doesn't "end" as it's a web application. Any re-entry to the website will likely to start a fresh session.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't. Application_End is fired with the hosting IIS process (w3wp.exe) terminates gracefully. The most likely cause of a graceful termination would be when IIS recycles the process as it does at a regular interval.

Answer (score 0):

No, the application_end event will not be triggered when an unhandled exception occurs. Application_Error will be triggered instead.

Typically, Application_End fires when the App pool is recycled or when you restart IIS.